# How to close the scroll function of a collectionview?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I do not want to the collectionView to Scroll but only want it to display as a list as its height.

But it seems there is no property to close the function.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you have to display a list of items without scrolling, why don't you use exactly `ListView` with disabled scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **CollectionView** is currently a preview, and lacks some of its planned functionality. In addition, the API may change as the implementation is completed.

So ,as Денис Чорный said, thought you just want it display just like a list.You can replace it with listview .

for more detail about collectview you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/)